# In what way is Ruby on Rails NOT multithreaded?

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails, multithreading, concurrency

**Disclaimer**: I'm a c# ASP.NET developer learning "RoR". Sorry if this question doesn't "get" RoR, any corrections greatly appreciated!

## What is multithreading

My understanding of "multithread" ability in web apps is twofold:

1. Every time a web/app server receives a request it can assign a thread to the new request, thus multiple requests can run concurrently.
2. The app runtime + language allows for multiple threads to be used WITHIN a single request (in ASP.NET via "Async" methods and keywords **for example**).

In this way, IIS7 + ASP.NET can do points 1 AND 2.

## I'm confused about RoR

I've read these two articles and they have left me confused:

- [Clearing up some things about LinkedIn mobile’s move from Rails to
  node.js](http://ikaisays.com/2012/10/04/clearing-up-some-things-about-linkedin-mobiles-move-from-rails-to-node-js/)
- [How to deploy a multi-threaded Rails app](http://www.jordanhollinger.com/2011/04/23/how-to-deploy-a-multi-threaded-rails-app)

### question one.

I think I understand that RoR doesn't lend itself very well to point number 2 above, that is, having multiple threads within the same request, have I got that right?

### question two.

Just to be crystal clear, RoR app/web servers can also do point number 1 above right (that is, multiple requests can run concurrently)? is that not always the case with RoR?

Comment: hey boltclock, could you leave at least one asp.net tag? Usually developers aren't learning from scratch, but instead migrating, and I think having the ASP.NET tag is helpful for other c sharpers...? For example, I much rather prefer "Objective C for c# developers", than, "learn Objective C without any context!" ;-)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Question 1:**
You can spawn more Ruby threads in one request if you want, although that seems to be outside the typical use case for Rails. There are uses for it for certain long-running IO or external operations.

**Question 2:**
The limiting factor for Ruby concurrency in general, not just with Rails, is the [`Global Interpreter Lock`](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2012/02/06/the-ruby-global-interpreter-lock).  This feature of Ruby prevents more than 1 thread of Ruby from executing at any given time per process.  The lock is released whenever there is non-Ruby code executing, such as waiting for disk IO or SQL responses.  You can get around this by using a different implementation of Ruby than the default, such as JRuby, but not all.

[Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) uses process based concurrency to handle a few requests concurrently, so, strictly speaking, is not "multithreaded," but is still concurrent.

[This talk from Ruby MidWest 2011](http://www.confreaks.com/videos/768-rubymidwest2011-high-performance-ruby-threading-versus-evented) has some good thoughts on getting multithreaded Ruby on Rails going.

Comment: +1 great answer! thanks kjw. Geez... so, in terms of point 2, how is RoR so popular, this seems like a massive problem in terms of scale, is that right?

Comment: It is considered a problem by some people, and there has been discussion of this issue for years.  The upside of Rails is faster development time, the downside is it doesn't scale as efficiently.  Note that it does still scale up if you throw more hardware at it, so there isn't a scale "ceiling," but it doesn't scale as efficiently as, say, a Java app.

Comment: @kjw0188 Agreed. I ended up replacing Rails pieces of code with Go which outperformed. Never had any luck with Rails and multithreading, even for trivial cases.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is about "from ASP.NET to RoR" there is another small but important detail to remember: In *nix environments it's common to achieve concurrency of a service application through multi-processing rather than multi-threading. This is an architecture that goes way back and is related to the relatively cheap cost of multi-processing on *nix systems using [fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) and [Copy-on-Write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write). Each process serves one request at a time in a single thread and the main process controls spawning and killing worker child processes. Multiple requests are served concurrently by different child processes.

Modern service applications, for example Apache, have multi-process, multi-threaded, and even combined modes (where the service forks several processes, each running several threads).

In cases where the application was built with portability at mind (examples again: Apache, MySQL, etc) it is customary to run it in multi-process or combined mode on *nix systems, and in multi-threaded mode on Windows servers.

However, admittedly Rails is somewhat lacking on the Windows front. It's not that you can't run it on Windows, it's just that not a lot of effort went into making sure it runs well and smoothly for production use on Windows servers. It's not a common production platform among the RoR community.

As a result, Eventhough Rails itself is thread-safe since version 2.2, there isn't yet a good multi-threaded server for it on Windows servers. And you get the best results by running it on *nix servers using multi-process/single-threaded concurrency model.

Answer (score 2):

Rails as a framework is thread-safe. So, the answer is yes!

The second link that you posted here names many of the Rails servers that don't do well with multi-threading. He later mentions that nginx is the way to go (it is definitely the most popular one and highly recommended). But he doesn't mention what made him come up to the conclusions.
Ruby 1.9.3 came out recently and has some new threading goodness built in which didn't exist before.

Use of multi-threading generally depends on the use case.
Personally I have tried it once an year ago and it had worked but I haven't used it in any production code because I haven't come across a use case where using multi-threading made more sense over pushing the long running task to a background job.

I would love to explore this more. So, if you can describe what you are trying to achieve then maybe we can do a POC.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this Vibhor! However, could you clarify your answer a bit, still not sure what your answer is. You said the answer is "yes", but what was the question to that "yes" answer?! ;-) If you could clarify a bit that would be awesome. thanks.

Comment: I've been following many discussions around this topic and the conclusion is that your best bet with multi-threading on rails would be by using jRuby which supports native threads. However you might be limited by the choice of ruby gems (libraries) available to you.